# Speed of 2-Norm calculation of matrices in NumPy

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have two matrices `x` and `y` for which I want to calculate the row-wise 2-norm. The shape of `x` is M x N, the shape of `y` is O x P x N. The following code is used to calculate the norm:

```
norm_x = np.expand_dims(np.sqrt(np.multiply(x, x).sum(axis=-1)), axis=-1)
norm_y = np.expand_dims(np.sqrt(np.multiply(y, y).sum(axis=-1)), axis=-1)
```

Although, this code can be executed in about 6ms in most cases, it can happen in rare cases (roughly 1/30), that the execution of this code takes up to 6s!

The same issue arises with these lines using `np.linalg.norm`:

```
norm_x = np.expand_dims(np.linalg.norm(x, axis=-1), axis=-1)
norm_y = np.expand_dims(np.linalg.norm(y, axis=-1), axis=-1)
```

I exactly know that it's these lines of code because I took the time of every chunk of code in this method.

What could be the reason and how could it be solved?

Minimal working example:

```
import time

import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(8, 300)
y = np.random.rand(227, 36, 300)

for i in range(1000000):
    start = time.time()
    norm_x = np.linalg.norm(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    norm_y = np.linalg.norm(y, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    end = time.time()
    dur = end - start

    # this code usually runs within 5ms
    # if it takes more than 100ms, something's odd
    if dur > 0.1:
        print(f"Iteration {i} took {dur}s")
```

Comment: Don't hand-roll it, use `np.linalg.norm`. How can you tell that it's these lines being slow and not something else? Imports  for instance can take long.

Comment: I take the time before and after every chunk of code in this method and log its duration. And yes, `np.linalg.norm` shows the same behaviour. My colleague suggest me to use the above lines of code because he thinks that `np.linalg.norm` might not be as efficient for matrices as above definition. But in fact, they are comparable in time consumption and show the same behaviour.

Comment: Which data type do `x` and `y` have? In which way do the cases with different runtime differ?

Comment: `x` and `y` both contain floats. The data is always exactly the same. In fact, I just spammed the function with the same data over and over and found that in some cases, the calculation is slow. I suspect that it might be some memory-internal issue, where maybe data is moved in memory in some cases. But I'm not sure how likely this is.

Comment: Also the actual size of your arrays could be important. I'd try exporting the arrays in problematic cases (checking the runtimes) to see if there's any hint there. But I suspect an unrelated slow-down.

Comment: At least on my machine (Linux), I can replicate this issue fairly consistently (with some patience) and it's always these 2 lines. Therefore, I think there might be an issue. `x.shape` is (8, 300) and `y.shape` (227, 36, 300).

Comment: Are you running this in a loop or are you firing up a new interpreter each time? We'd probably have to look at a reproducing [mcve] complete with timing.

Comment: No, it's running in the same interpreter instance, but re-starting the interpreter does not solve this issue. The actual code is behind a Flask API and I send REST queries to start it. However, I observed this issue in a test script as well that I wrote to compare the new batch-wise implementation with the old one. I prepare an MWE now.

Comment: I added an MWE now. In one case, it took 2.9s, all other cases it just ran through. Hopefully, it's reproducible. I wanted to dump the actual matrices inside this code, but it'd become too big.

Comment: Can you reproduce it in the cloud e.g. in a Google Colab or Repl.it env? I suspect the issue is with your system rather than in the code.

Comment: Ok, it seems that there is no other reason for this code to be slow in rare cases other than my system hanging sometimes. Actually, I thought that if it's my system hanging, it should not be as reproducible for me as it is now. If always another part of the code would hang, it'd be a sign for me that it's a delay of the system. However, I pasted my MWE into https://repl.it/repls/MassiveFloralwhiteOpensoundsystem#main.py and found that in rare cases, the runtime is >0.1s there as well, while the mean time is around 0.015s. However, this difference is not as pronounced as it is on my system.

Comment: At Monday, I'll deploy the code into our test cloud and check whether or not the speed issue can be observed on that system as well. I'll post an update then.

Comment: The reason you may be observing this slowdown only for these two lines may be related to your script execution time being dominated by those two lines. The slowdown itself is likely OS-related.

Comment: If I store `dur` for 100000 iterations in ipython and plot them on a histogram with 50 bins I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUIYX.png (note the log scale). With 10000 iterations I don't see the small peak below 0.02. Overall it seems reasonable, all things considered. I wonder if your histogram looks differently.

Comment: You could re-check using process_time() instead of time(). If your system is busy occasionally while doing this computation (for whatever reason), the wall time duration of this computation will grow. The process time should not grow in that case. If the process time actually peaks, that'd quite scary imho.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine (with Python 3.8.3 on Linux 5.6): the average execution time is 2.5ms/iteration. No iteration took more than 20 ms which is fine. Do you run out of memory? Do you have other (intensive) processes running in parallel?

Comment: Ok, I tried again many times now and I cannot observe a slowdown anymore. So, it must have been a special situation and there is no special relation to those 2 lines. Thank you for your suggestions and sorry everyone for this false alarm.